# Java - available garbage collection algorithms

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Does anyone know a proper resource to read on the available garbage collection mechanisms in java? So far I found a couple of websites but they did not contain a comprehensive description with respect to when to use which and what the implementation was. (I am referring to Oracle's jdk)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/gc-142724.html

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) is what I keep coming back to. It has pictures and everything.

Comment: Any chance to get the spec for java 7? I guess they added sth called G1 collector

Comment: @Bober02 In the link I provided: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As of today, there are 4 GC algorithms available in the Java Hotspot VM:

- The **Serial GC** - recommended for client-style applications that do not have low pause time requirements.
- The **Parallel GC** - use when the throughput matters.
- The **Mostly-Concurrent GC** (also known as Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC(CMS)) - use when the latency matters.
- The **Garbage First GC** (G1) - new GC algorithm, for CMS replacement.

You can find more information about these GC algorithms in the references below.

Books:

- [Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528) - practical guide, contains chapters on GC, explains comprehensively when and how to use various Hotspot GC algorithms,
- [The Garbage Collection Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795) - Garbage-Collection theory explained, mentions all available GC techniques.

Talks/Articles:

- Java One 2012 [Advanced JVM Tuning](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=7236)
- Java One 2012 [G1 Garbage Collector Performance Tuning](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=6583&tclass=popup)
- [Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Garbage+Collection+%28GC%29+Tuning+Guide)
- [Java HotSpot Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/gc-142724.html)

Mailing List:

- [OpenJDK Hotspot GC Use](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-gc-use)

Comment: Then what about Parallel Old GC (Parallel Compacting GC)? Is it an extended version of parallel GC that use in old generation memory?