# How java G1 collected object for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I want know the difference between CMS (concurrent-mark-sweep) and G1.
Does G1 mark the garbage collecting object as earlier CMS work or it is using some different algorithm.

Comment: The resources here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616919/java-available-garbage-collection-algorithms/15621173#15621173 - should allow you to understand the G1 collector